# "$injector:modulerr" : throwing error for module name is not available but actually it is available

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started learning angularjs I tried this code : 
In the file angularmy.js

```
var myname = angular.module("myModule",[]);
myname.controller("myController" , function($scope){
$scope.message = "Hello lady";
});
```

In HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html  >
    <head> 
        <script src = "angular.js"></script>
        <script src = "angularmy.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app = "myname"  >
        <div id="div1" ng-controller = "myController">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It's throwing error saying  **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myname due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myname' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**
    But the module name is "myname" only, then why am I gettig the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a typo. It need to be

```
var myname = angular.module("myname",[]);
```

Also note it is better to use **[Inline Array Annotation](http://Using%20the%20inline%20array%20annotation)** when injecting dependencies.

Else you may see this same error while running the application with minified code

```
//Note `[` brace
myname.controller("myController" ,['$scope, function($scope){ 
//Rest of code
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... it is indeed that but it wasn't a typo I thought I should use "myname" as the module name in html and not "myModule"

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-app name should be myModule not myname in HTML. --> `ng-app="myModule"`